# Armorer Bug in HD Remake

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

**Was the old *Armorer Bug* fixed in the recent HD Remake** (the new release on Steam, not to be confused with the fan-made HD Mod of the original) **of Heroes of Might and Magic III?**

The original version of the game had a now **(in)famous glitch** in which the **armorer skill actually worked in reverse specifically against siege towers** (made you more vulnerable against them). I recall it was revealed to be one of those super simple, brain-fart programming bugs where some guy once accidentally put a divided-by sign where he meant to put a multiply-by sign, or some such.

Was this bug fixed in this remake?  I know that the team made some bug fixes, but also left a lot identical to how it was as well, so it seems really up-in-the-air.  I have not had luck asking on the Steam forums.

Comment: It seems to still be there according to [this bug report](http://steamcommunity.com/app/297000/discussions/0/604941528473197086/#c604941528488465147)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Plausible but not entirely convincing as evidence.  This person might just be citing what they know of the old glitch and may not have tested it in the new version.

Comment: Try HotA addon, it fixes a lot of gameplay bugs including the (arrow towers + armorer) one you asked about and improves balance. (full list of changes: http://forum.df2.ru/index.php?showtopic=32286) It's also fully compatible with fan-made HD mod you mentioned. IMO it's the best kind of Heroes 3 nowadays. BTW, HD mod is actually better that Ubisoft's joke, even in terms of graphics, as crazy as it sounds. (if you are using HiDPI monitor, try using smarter scaling, like Scale2x and others, they do wonders)

Comment: @SargeBorsch I do enjoy HotA, yes.  It's an excellent mod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bug is still there in HD Remake.**

I've run following tests. I've created this map in editor:

[image]

Blue town has Castle, red heroes (A and B) are both lvl 1 Clerics with 0 Defense and have army of 100 Goblins (2 Defense creatures, for some reason Peasants are not available in my editor). Hero A has Armorer Expert. I run multiple sieges and took notes of damage done by top tower (it deals more damage than side towers) - I've put down 50 attacks in every experiment. Then I've edited heroes again and gave them both different artifacts giving total +22 Defense. Results are the following:

```
Experiment | Total Damage | Average Damage
A          |    757       |   15.14
A + 22 Def |    753       |   15.06
B          |    743       |   14.86   
B + 22 Def |    745       |   14.9
```

# of experiments is not that great, but with no way to automate it I don't want to run more :)